# Прямая речь или цитирование

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, прямая-речь

Это прямая речь или просто цитата? Просто непонятно: если цитата, зачем двоеточие?

**Как верноподданечески цитируют на сайте «Новый нижний» директора компании застройкu, которую любовно именуют «Светлана Семеновна»: «Верующий человек каждое своё дело должен начинать с молитвы, с благословения. Такая у нас установка».**

Comment: Полное название: «Городской информационный сайт Новый Нижний»,  присутствует в рубрике: Информационные сайты. http://newnn.ru/  ====== Чтобы со строчной, как в вопросе, быть не может

Comment: так было написано,и мне нужен ответ по такой фразе,а не видоизменять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корявая фраза, нельзя ее оставлять в таком виде. Минимальная правка:

**Как верноподданечески цитируют на сайте «Новый нижний» директора компании застройкu, которую любовно именуют Светланой Семеновной, «верующий человек каждое своё дело должен начинать с молитвы, с благословения. Такая у нас установка».**

А еще лучше так:

**Как говорит  директор компании-застройщика, которую верноподданечески цитирует сайт «Новый нижний», любовно именуя ее Светланой Семеновной, «верующий человек каждое своё дело должен начинать с молитвы, с благословения. Такая у нас установка».**

Не уверен по поводу строчной буквы в начале цитаты. Надеюсь, другие участники помогут.

Или так:

**Сайт «Новый нижний» верноподданечески цитирует директора компании-застройщика, любовно именуя ее Светланой Семеновной: «Верующий человек каждое своё дело должен начинать с молитвы, с благословения. Такая у нас установка».**

Дополнение.

Как выяснилось, автор вопроса хочет получить объяснения, а не изменения.
Я думал, что после слов "как цитирует", "как сказал" цитата не может передаваться в форме прямой речи, но нашел примеры в Нацкорпусе:

**Как цитирует Монтень из Плутарха: «Если пожелать выразить единым словом и свести к одному все правила нашей жизни, то придется сказать, что мудрость ― это всегда желать и всегда не желать одной и той же вещи».** [Самуил Лурье. Поступки, побуждения, слова // «Звезда», 2002]

**Как сказал философ: "Второго раза не бывает".** [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Значит можно дать такое объяснение: автор цитирует сайт "Новый нижний", который в свою очередь цитирует директора, и предает это как прямую речь.

Comment: большое спасибо)

Comment: "Новый Нижний". У нас в печати такие ошибки часто пропускают